# Error in opening ExcelConnection C# VS2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to import a .csv file into my database. I am able to import an excel worksheet into my database, however due to different file format as .csv as from .xls, I need to make an import function specially for .csv.

Below is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    // Get the name of the Excel spreadsheet to upload. 
    string strFileName = Server.HtmlEncode(FileUpload1.FileName);

    // Get the extension of the Excel spreadsheet. 
    string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(strFileName);

    // Validate the file extension. 
    if (strExtension != ".xls" && strExtension != ".xlsx" && strExtension != ".csv" && strExtension != ".csv")
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Failed to import DEM Conflicting Role Datasheet. Cause: Invalid Excel file.');</script>");
        return;
    }

                // Generate the file name to save. 
        string strUploadFileName = @"C:\Documents and Settings\rhlim\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\SoD\UploadFiles\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + strExtension;

        // Save the Excel spreadsheet on server. 
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(strUploadFileName);

        // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
        string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strUploadFileName + ";Extended Properties=Text;";
        using (OleDbConnection ExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connStr)){
        OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [columns] FROM +userrolelist", ExcelConnection);

        OleDbDataAdapter ExcelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ExcelCommand);

        ExcelConnection.Open();

    using (DbDataReader dr = ExcelCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // SQL Server Connection String
        string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=<IP>;Initial Catalog=<DB>;User ID=<userid>;Password=<password>";

        // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                   new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "DEMUserRoles";
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
            Response.Write("<script>alert('DEM User Data imported');</script>");

        }
    }
    }
}
else Response.Write("<script>alert('Failed to import DEM User Roles Data. Cause: No file found.');</script>");
```

}

The file has been successfully saved, but the error says that the path for the file is not valid, even though the file has been successfully saved as .csv, therefore I am not able to continue with the process of importing the data into my database.

Below are the screenshots of my error:
[image]
[image]

In conclusion I am having the error that the file path which the csv file is saved is not valid, although the csv file is successfully saved. Need some help from experienced. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection string Data Source should only contain the *path* to your CSV file. It should not contain the CSV file name.

The file name is specified in the SQL statement as a table.

```
string dir = @"C:\Documents and Settings\rhlim\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\SoD\UploadFiles\";
string mycsv = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + strExtension;

string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dir + ";Extended Properties=Text;";

OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand(
    "SELECT [columns] FROM " + mycsv, ExcelConnection);
```

Comment: Thanks campbell, it seems working for me. However I am having some issues when converting pipe delimited text file to .csv files, and some columns variables kind of split into two parts and skipped to the next column, messing up the row, so I have to troubleshoot why is it so. Do you mind taking a look at my code I used for converting pipe delimited file to .csv file? Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061307/rows-messed-up-when-converting-pipe-delimited-text-files-to-csv-excel-file-c-sh

this is the error i'm facing currently, i have no clue why the conversion had errors in it.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly NOT recommend you to use OLE to access to Excel documents. There's an infinite number of glitches and bugs.
In general, using sql to access the data when different cells of one column can contain different data types - is nonsense. But even without this there are enough bugs.

Use COM objects for Excel. Otherwise, you will have a hard - trust me on the floor :-)

Comment: +1 Going through that, I returned to `Interop` faster than I thought.

Comment: @MichałPowaga, yeah, I have similar experiences. :-)