# Rows messed up when converting pipe delimited text files to .CSV excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, excel, visual-studio-2005

I code this function which converts all pipes into commas, and after that converting it into an excel .CSV file.

However, after that I realize that there are some problems with some rows.

E.g. Name [Chua Wei Loon] (supposedly to be in one column), ended up "Chua Wei" is in one column, "Loon" is in the next column.

I have look through the text file and find no pipes in between the name, and I couldn't find a solution to it.

Below is my code for the function:

```
protected void SaveAsExcelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        //string strExcelOutputFilename = "C:/Documents and Settings/rhlim/My Documents/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + xlExtension;

        // Before attempting to import the file, verify 
        // that the FileUpload control contains a file. 
        if (TextFile.HasFile)
        {
            // Get the name of the Excel spreadsheet. 
            string strFileName = Server.HtmlEncode(TextFile.FileName);

            // Get the extension of the text. 
            string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(strFileName);

            // Validate the file extension. 
            if (strExtension != ".TXT" && strExtension!=".txt")
            {

                Response.Write("<script>alert('Invalid text file!');</script>");
                return;
            }

            // Generate the file name to save the text file.
            //string strUploadFileName = "C:/Documents and Settings/rhlim/My Documents/Visual Studio 2005/WebSites/SoD/UploadFiles/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + strExtension;

            if (DEMUserRoleRB.Checked)
            {
                string strExcelOutputFilename = "C:/" + "userrolelist" + xlExtension;


                using (StreamWriter outputWriter = new StreamWriter(File.Create(strExcelOutputFilename)))
                {
                    StreamReader inputReader = new StreamReader(TextFile.FileContent);
                    string fileContent = inputReader.ReadToEnd();
                    fileContent = fileContent.Replace('|', ',');
                    outputWriter.Write(fileContent);
                    //TextFile.SaveAs(strExcelOutputFilename);
                    inputReader.Close();
                    UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Conversion successful. File is stored at directory C:/";
                }

                //string strExcelOutputFilename = "C:/Documents and Settings/rhlim/My Documents/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")+xlExtension;
                // Save the Excel spreadsheet on server. 
                //TextFile.SaveAs (strExcelOutputFilename);

            }
        }
        else Response.Write("<script>alert('Please select a file');</script>");
```

A sample output of the .csv file (rows with errors are highlighted):

[image]

I have realized my mistake, it is due to having commans inside variables which caused the name to split.

Are there any suggestions so that I could still convert them to .csv files despite having commans in between variables?

Comment: my guess is that the row with "Chua Wei | Loon" was originally "Chua Wei, Loon"  When you converted all the pipes to commas, you were not taking into account that there might be commas in the data in the columns (hence why they were pipe delimited to begin with?)  You might need to add double quotes around where the pipes were, so that you would get "Chua Wei, Loon", "Normal User", etc.

Comment: Can you just show us the actual text data created?  It is just a .xls file that is actual text, until excel opens it and re-saves it.  Open it with notepad or in vs.net directly and see what the data is.  Seems pretty simple to debug.

Comment: double quotes where the pipes were? Meaning that I will have to change fileContent = fileContent.Replace('|', ','); to fileContent = fileContent.Replace("|", ',');  ?

Comment: I've realized my mistakes, it was due to having commans in between the name variable. Are there any way I could change the ',' to instead of using commas to convert?

Comment: not quite... more like replace "|" with "\",\""

Comment: i've tried to replace '|' with "\",\", and they prompted error that says "The best method overload method match for 'string.Replace(string, string)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: that's because it needs to be "|"  treat both of them as a string.  You might then need to add a double quote at the beginning and at the end of your full string, or maybe just each row.

Comment: I have used fileContent = fileContent.Replace(""\",\", ','"); it gives me an error at the first \, saying Unexpected chracter"\"

Comment: try :   fileContent.Replace("|", "\",\"");

Comment: The file can be successfully created, but when I tried opening the file, it says that The file contains more than 1,048,576 rows or 16,384 columns. Guess it couldn't work

Comment: I suppose the file has more than 1,048,576 rows, in which case, it would be easy to split the file into several files, each with 1,048,576 rows or fewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check whether [Chua Wei Loon] is not actually [Chua Wei, Loon] ?  Did you get rid of the commas in the data first?

Comment: Oh yes, I have checked and there are indeed commans in between them. Shucks, if thats the case I can't convert to .csv anymore :(

Comment: well... throwing out the commas first is an option of course.
fileContent = fileContent.Replace(',', ' ');

Answer (score 0):

The input files are pipe delimited because the data includes commas.  Changing the delimiters to commas will therefore cause the problem you're seeing.  Solution: keep the pipe delimiters.  Why do you feel you need to replace them?  I'm sure Excel can read pipe-delimited files.

Comment: I am not sure how to code for pipe-delimited files too .xls files. If there are sample codes out there it would really help.

Comment: How are you loading the comma-delimited file in Excel?

Comment: I've realized my mistakes, it was due to having commans in between the name variable. Are there any way I could change the ',' to instead of using commas to convert?

Comment: My intention was to import the data in the excel sheet into my SQL database, therefore I would want to convert pipe-delimited text files into excel files, preferably in .xls format

Comment: Just load the text file with the pipe delimiters into Excel.  The Workbooks.Open method has a Delimiter you would use to specify the pipe character.  Then save the file in XLS format.  But SQL Server must have a way of importing delimited text files directly.  Don't use Excel if you don't have to.

Comment: I have done importing .xls data into sql and all the import checks for .xls or .csv format, so i do not wish to redo everything and change it to just pipe to sql database, it would be kind of wasted effort. so now i just need a code which is able to convert a pipe delimited file to .xls format. That will be great

Comment: For that you will need to use Excel interop, or some other library that can create XLS files.